# remote developer pay - carreers 2.0

Tags: telecommute

I don't know what's best place to post that question so I'm posting it here. I'm curios whether US companies pay as much or a little less for a developer working remotely from other country than for a developer working on-site? I mean is it feasible to make 80-120k a year working from home? Is there anyone here working remotely and making around the figures I mentioned above who can share his experience? PS. If it's OFF-topic, please direct me where this question would be a good fit. I didn't find any forum on carreers 2.0 website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

US companies (and companies in other countries) pay based on the value they receive, and based on the market conditions for employees in which they compete.

It's *feasible* to make almost any amount, working almost anywhere. But whether it is likely or not is totally dependent on what you bring to the table.

If you are a world-class developer, with an industry-leading reputation, you can probably work wherever you choose.

I've worked at companies that paid US wages for a few folks that decided to go back home to India. But they were special cases in that they had already worked with us in the US for years, and we completely trusted them to work on their own overseas. But when we hired most folks in India we paid them prevailing (India) wages. The same was true for a few folks in China.